# Q: CodeceptJS "unknown error": call function result missing 'value'

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

This is my Test

```
 Feature('Test');

    Scenario('test something', (I) => {

        I.amOnPage("");
        I.see("Welcome");
        I.fillField('j_username', 'xxxxxx');
        I.wait(3);
    });
```

This is my codeceptjs.JSON

```
{
  "tests": "asd/*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "smartwait":"1000",
  "helpers": {
    "WebDriverIO": {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/xxxx/",
      "browser": "chrome"
    }
  },
  "include": {
    "I": "./steps_file.js"
  },
  "bootstrap": false,
  "name": "yenideneme"
}
```

I am try CodeceptJS with Webdriverio helper for end-to-end tests. Connect to the server and `I.see("")` passed. But added `I.fillField()` taken this Error=

```
test something:
unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
```

I try to update chrome and chromedriver but not worked.

And other project  taken Error=
 
 `2) e2e
       "after each" hook: finalize codeceptjs for "welcome Page @fristBlank":
     unknown error: call function result missing 'value'`

[image: Error Pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be related to an issue with Chrome 65. After upgrading from Chrome 64, I started seeing the same issue. Downgrading to the version 64 should help temporarily.

A long-term solution is making sure that Chromedriver is upgraded to version 2.36, which is supposed to work with Chrome 65. However, a simple "npm install chromedriver" may not be sufficient. Your Selenium may still try to load the old version. The actual solution depends on your environment setup.

Comment: I uninstall all thing after install  but not worked. Getting same Error.

Comment: After poking around I found that my selenium-standalone was running its default setting which has chromedriver-2.33 no matter which version I installed. There is a pull request with a fix on GitHub already. Meanwhile, in order to fix the issue, you can run your selenium-standalone with the following comand:

`selenium-standalone start --drivers.chrome.version=2.36`

Comment: I try this command but not working. As you have stated chrome and selenium-standalone update request when running test or open chrome. For this reason install chrome 64 version and close chrome update. if dont disable chrome update, chrome update request all time and getting incompatibility problem. Selenium-standalone update not a problem for running. Problem solved really thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem yesterday after a chrome update(v65).

Uninstalled and downloaded version 63 from this site.

http://www.geocities.jp/ecvcn/exam/chrome_installer.html

Problem Solved.

Comment: VVO just updated the selenium-standalone package. please update it and it will work with the chrome version 65.